# No sound in webex player in wine

Tags: audio, wine

I am using Fedora Core 10. I have installed wine with both `wine-alsa` and `wine-oss` sound drivers. I am able to hear test sounds by running `winecfg`, but when I run the webex player there is no sound, and the option to increase volume is disabled. I am not sure whether the problem is with wine or with webex; how can I debug/fix this?

Comment: I use webex for remote support and although Ive never tested audio or video for that matter it does work seamlessly in Ubuntu 10.04 with chrome. Maybe you could try running it natively inside Fedora